# Whereas vs although vs while

Tags: difference, word-difference

In most cases, the way I see it, these words mean the same thing in context:

- Whereas/although/while this car is old it is still very popular and pricey.

How do I choose one or another or is there no difference between them?

I mean, should it bother me to care to choose one and not any other in certain contexts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these all are different words with different meanings.  There are *some* circumstances where all three might *work*, but that doesn't mean all work in *all* circumstances.

*Whereas* is much more formal and is used in things like legal documents and formal proofs.  It means the same as "given" or "presuming", and is really little more than a preface to some logical statement:  "*whereas* A is true, we can conclude B".

*Whereas* can also be used to contrast two statements in much the same way as "but" or "however", in a more formal way:  "Whereas A is true in one case, B is true in another"

> **Whereas** the plaintiff was given many warnings about the dangers of his product, he cannot now claim he should bear no responsibility to the defendants who were injured by it.

*Although* is common and generally means *despite* or *regardless of*: "although* A may be true, it is not relevant to B".

> **Although** the plaintiff was given many warnings about the dangers of his product, those dangers are inherent to its use and clearly iterated in the user manual, and the defendants should assume full responsibility for the risk.

*While* is common and generally means *concurrent or included with*: "while A may be true, B is also true".

> **While** it is true the use of the product is inherently risky,  the issue lies in the plaintiff's faulty design, not the way the product was used.

Again, there is some overlap in many contexts, because each represents similar logic.

Comment: So, basically, when I have a sentence like the one I do now then any of the three will do, but depending on the style and stress I can pick the word I want?

Comment: @SovereignSun  Yes, as long as each works for the context.  These three words are not *synonyms*, but since each can be used to make logical statements, you can use the one that best fits your logic.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the idea you want to express is that you prefer to get wet over carrying an umbrella; it is raining but *nonetheless* you are not going to carry an umbrella:

> Although it is raining, I refuse to bring an umbrella. <sup>OK</sup>
>
> Whereas it is raining, I refuse to bring an umbrella. <sup>not
>   OK</sup>
>
> While it is raining, I refuse to bring an umbrella. <sup>not a perfectly clear expression of the idea</sup>

In most non-legalistic contexts in contemporary English, **whereas** can be understood as a synonym for **yet** or **to the contrary**:

> You bring an umbrella whereas|while|yet I do not. <sup>OK</sup>

It introduces a clause that runs contrary to the idea expressed by the previous assertion.

In legalistic contexts, **whereas** works like **Since** or **Given the fact that**:

> Whereas Customer wishes to purchase platinum-plated electrical connectors and Vendor is in the business of providing such connectors, therefore the two parties do hereby agree ...

Answer (score 2):

> ***Although/though*** can be used to contrast ideas. Although/though are subordinating conjunctions used to connect a subordinate clause to a main clause, like after, as, before, if, since, that, even though, even if.
>
> ***But cannot be used in the same way as although/though**. We use but to connect items which are the same grammatical type (coordinating conjunction).
>
> - *We’ve still enjoyed our holiday, **although** it rained a lot.*
> - *It rained a lot **but** we’ve still enjoyed our holiday.*
> - ***Not***: But it rained a lot, we’ve still enjoyed our holiday.
>
> ***Although can sound more formal than but***. Though is much more common in speaking than in writing. Although is much more common in writing than in speaking.

From [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/linking-words-and-expressions/conjunctions-contrasting)

> ***While and whilst*** mean the same when we use them as conjunctions. They both mean ‘***during the time that something else happens***’, or ‘in contrast with something else’. ***While is much more common than whilst, and whilst sounds more formal:***
>
> - Would you like something to eat while we’re waiting? (less common: … whilst we’re waiting?) (during the time we’re waiting)

From [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/linking-words-and-expressions/while-and-whilst)

> ***We use the conjunction whereas to indicate a contrast between two facts or ideas:***
>
> - *He loves foreign holidays, whereas his wife prefers to stay at home.*
> - *Whereas most new PCs have several USB slots, older ones often only had one.*

***Note that:***

> Whereas means the same as while in sentences expressing contrasts. It does not mean the same as while when while refers to time:

From [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/linking-words-and-expressions/whereas)